# "Criterion" VS "Benchmark"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I was wondering whether both the following choices can be used in my made-up examples bellow without any specific change in the sentences' meanings:

**Case 1)** 
Steve) What is your ............. to chose your future spouse? 
Sam) To me, honesty is far more important than anything else. 
**a. criterion** 
**b. benchmark**

**Case 2)** 
What ........... do you use to decide whether one book is better than another? 
**a. criteria** 
**b. benchmarks**

> **Criterion:**

**A standard** that you use to **judge something or make a decision** about something. 
**Example** - the criteria we use to select candidates.

[Source:](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/criterion)

> **Benchmark:**

**Something that is used as a standard** by which other things can be **judged or measured**. 
**Example:** - Figures that are a useful benchmark for measuring the company’s performance.

[Source:](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/benchmark)

I think they both mean the same in both of the examples above with NO significant change in the meanings. However, I need your approval on my take here.

Comment: criterion **for choosing** a spouse.  If you are not married, spouse doe not require the word future.

Answer (score 2):

They don't mean the same.

If you use criteria, you say "The chosen person must have these qualities".

If you use something as a benchmark, you say "The chosen one must be as good, or nearly as good as this one".